# null pointer exception error using action listener

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, syntax-error, actionlistener

I'm getting the error message null pointer exception on the line img.setIcon(bg); in the controller class in my action listener and I'm not sure why. I've commented where the error is highlighted. Any ideas on why?

```
    public class Display {
    public ImageIcon bg;
    public JLabel img;
    public void UI() {
        Controller listener = new Controller();
        bg = new ImageIcon("prophase.png");
        img = new JLabel(bg, JLabel.CENTER);
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        JPanel imgPane = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        imgPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setOpaque(false);// !!
        top.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        bottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("What stage of mitosis is this?", JLabel.CENTER);
        imgPane.add(img);// center
        top.add(jl);// top center
        top.add(listener.wordListener());// top center
        bottom.add(listener.answer);// bottom
        panel1.add(imgPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);// background image (center)
        panel1.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);// text field and jlabel (top)
        panel1.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);// blank spaces and letters used
        gameFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar());
        gameFrame.setTitle("Mitosis");
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("logo.png").getImage());
        gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        gameFrame.add(panel1);
        gameFrame.setSize(400, 300);
        gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

another class:

```
 public class Controller {
    Display display = new Display();
    private JFrame dialogFrame = new JFrame();
    private ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("logo.png");
    public String word;
    public JLabel answer = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.CENTER);
        public JTextField wordListener() {
            JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
            tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// right click key
                    JTextField tf = (JTextField) e.getSource();
                    word = tf.getText();
                    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("Prophase")) {
                        answer.setText("Correct!");
                        ImageIcon bg = display.bg;
                        JLabel img = display.img;
                        bg = new ImageIcon("interphase.png");
                        img.setIcon(bg);//error
                        answer.setText(" ");
                    } else {
                        answer.setText("Incorrect, try again.");
                    }
                    tf.setText("");
                }// end actionPerformed method
            });
            return tf;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something here is not right... What is "display" referring to in the second class?

Comment: @tf.alves Display is referring to the display class where i get my image icon(bg) and jlabel(img) from; which i declared as public so I can use them in the controller class.

Comment: So, you're saying that "display.bg" refers to an instance of the Display class which has a public variable called bg? Are you initialising the bg value in your constructor or in some other method before you call "display.bg"? Btw, I'd suggest you to use proper encapsulation, it pays off eventually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default constructor of `Display` doesn't initialize the attribute `img`, which is then initialized to `null` by default. The exception is clearly due to the fact that you are trying to use `img` without initializing it anywhere. You should define a default constructor for `Display` that does something like this:

```
public Display(){
    UI();
}
```

Because in `UI()` you are initializing `img`.
Also you have to initialize your `display` before using `img`, like this:

```
Display display = new Display();
```

Comment: could i call it using display.UI();   ? And is there a way so I could only call the image and not a new JFrame?

Comment: Yes you could simply call display.UI() instead of define a new constructor but you should do this only if, for some reasons, you cannot initialize img inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the path for your image is correct

```
bg = new ImageIcon("interphase.png");
```

If a resource is not found you will get a NullPointerException when you try to use that imageicon somewhere else.

Try something along the lines

```
getClass().getResource("interphase.png");
```

prepend the directory name if needed, in order to get to your image in your resources.

Also, make sure you are initialising the variable in the Display class before using it.

Comment: My image path is correct, and I am initializing the variable bg in the Display class with this bg = new ImageIcon("prophase.png"); but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Please try again with the getClass().getResource(), there's got to be something wrong with the image path. Have you tried to put a breakpoint right after you initialise that ImageIcon to see what you're getting?